# Issues when setting discounts and using special prices

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, rules, catalog, price

We recently launched a Prestashop store where we use Prestashops "Specific Prices" so customers in our own country get a special price and all other countries get the regular price.

We want to set a Catalog Price Rule, so all products get a 20% discount. The discount works fine, but all products that have a specific price, do not get the discount. Is there any way to override the specific price, so that all items on the store get a discount ?

We use [Geo Targeting Pro](https://www.prestaheroes.com/en-us/prestashop-geo-localization-solutions/69-geo-targeting-pro-price-by-country.html), might it have something to do with it ?

Maybe someone has had the same problem ?

Comment: So you have 2 specific prices for these products?

Comment: as I see presta developer changed that behaviour and now specific prices are not cumulative, so it can be changed only with module and/or core changes

Comment: Yes, @joseantgv, that is what is currently happening, but what we want is to create a discount for all items, also those that have a specific price. Say, we sell an item a for $5 in all countries and a specific price of $4 in, say, Denmark. We would like to set a 20% discount on all items, so that all countries the items sell for $4 but in Denmark we want the price to become $3.2.

Comment: @SergiiP, do you know of any moduls that have this functionality?

Comment: @LeviáTorkilsheyggi no, I only faced with module that does an opposite functionality - made discounts "non cumulative"